# Signalr cast IHubContext to actual Hub

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr-hub, self-hosting

I'm wondering if it's possible to Cast the result of
`var hub = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ChatHub>();`
To my actual ChatHub class.
Because `GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ChatHub>() as ChatHub` fails

On my ChatHub class I have a method UpdateTime():

```
public void SendTimeUpdate(DateTime time, string auth)
{
    Clients.All.UpdateTime(time, auth);
}
```

And I want to call it from my other class. Since I can't cast to ChatHub and invoke the SendUpdate I have to go:

```
GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ChatHub>().Clients.All.UpdateTime(time, auth);
```

But if I go this road, the method SendTimeUpdate isn't added in the proxy script /signalr/hubs

Is there a solution for this problem? I want to get the typed Hub instance and not call stuff directly on the Clients property of the IHubContext.

Comment: So the method `UpdateTime` needs to be defined in your client code. Could you post whatever javascript you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cannot cast the result of `....GetHubContext<....` to your hub class.  Sorry :(.

The GetHubContext approach returns an `IHubContext` when a Hub is only an `IHub`.

If you'd like to centralize the logic just make a method that you can call into from your hub and from your external service.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't your class just create a connection to your hub and call the method that way?

Comment: Hmm, yeah that will work but doesn't look like a best practise.